# Notification doubled in oreo?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.1-oreo

I have included oreo support in my app. Now compile and target SDK versions are 27. I have created one channel to get my notifications. I am calling the create channel method from application class. When the app is in foreground notifications looks fine. But the moment I receive a notification when the app is in background, default channel is getting created so that 1 default notification and 1 custom notifications are displayed in the notification tray. I am using the broadcast receiver to get the notification. Given below is my code.

Manifest.xml

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.PushMessageReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.caps" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="com.caps" />
```

Broadcast Receiver.java

```
public class PushMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    abortBroadcast();
    Logger.d(Logger.TAG, "notification received");
    if (intent != null) {
        NotificationHandler.handleNotification(context, formNotificationObject(intent));
    }

}

private Notification formNotificationObject(Intent intent) {
    Notification notification = new Notification();
    notification.setMessageId(TextUtils.isEmpty(intent.getStringExtra("messageid")) ?
            0 : Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("messageid")));
    notification.setTitle(intent.getStringExtra("title"));
    notification.setBody(intent.getStringExtra("body"));
    notification.setImage(intent.getStringExtra("image"));
    notification.setType(intent.getStringExtra("type"));
    notification.setUrl(intent.getStringExtra("url"));
    notification.setExpiry(intent.getStringExtra("expiry"));
    if (intent.hasExtra("param")) {
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("param");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            CFLProduct product = mapper.readValue(data, CFLProduct.class);
            notification.setParam(product);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return notification;
   }
   }
```

NotificationHandler.java

```
public class NotificationHandler {


private static final CharSequence ANDROID_CHANNEL_NAME = "Promotions";
private static final String ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID = "com.caps";
private static NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

public static void handleNotification(Context context, Notification notification) {
    if (notification != null) {
        Logger.d(Logger.TAG, notification.toString());
        showNotification(context, notification);

    } else {
        Logger.e(Logger.TAG, "notification is null");
    }

}

private static NotificationCompat.Builder getNotificationBuilder(Context context) {
    if (CommonUtils.isOreoOrAbove()) {

        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID);
    } else {
                   return new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    }
}

private static void showNotification(final Context context, final Notification notification) {
    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = getNotificationBuilder(context);
    builder.setContentTitle(notification.getTitle());
    builder.setContentText(notification.getBody());
    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    bigTextStyle.setBigContentTitle(notification.getTitle());
    bigTextStyle.bigText(notification.getBody());
    builder.setStyle(bigTextStyle);
    // Playing notification sound
    builder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    getNotificationIcon(context, builder);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra(AppConstants.BundleKeys.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(HomeActivity.class);
    final int id = new Random().nextInt(1000);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(id, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    if (CommonUtils.isValidUrl(notification.getImage())) {
       /* DownLoadBitMap downLoadBitMap = new DownLoadBitMap(context, builder, id, notification);
        downLoadBitMap.execute(notification.getImage());*/
        DownLoadBitmap downLoadBitmap = new DownLoadBitmap(context, builder, id, notification);
        downLoadBitmap.loadFromGlide();
    } else {
        showSmallNotification(context, builder, id);
    }
}


private static void getNotificationIcon(Context context, NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder) {

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_small_icon);
        notificationBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
    } else {
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }
}

private static void showSmallNotification(Context context, NotificationCompat.Builder builder, int id) {
    if (AppData.getInstance().getNotificationCount() == 0) {
        AppData.getInstance().setNotificationCount(1);
    }
    getManager(context).notify(id, builder.build());

}

private static void showBigNotification(Context context, NotificationCompat.Builder builder, Bitmap bitmap, int id, Notification notification) {
    if (AppData.getInstance().getNotificationCount() == 0) {
        AppData.getInstance().setNotificationCount(1);
    }
    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
    bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
    bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(notification.getTitle());
    bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(notification.getBody());
    builder.setStyle(bigPictureStyle);
    getManager(context).notify(id, builder.build());

}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public static void createChannels(Context context) {

    // create android channel
    NotificationChannel androidChannel = new NotificationChannel(ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID,
            ANDROID_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    // Sets whether notifications posted to this channel should display notification lights
    androidChannel.enableLights(true);
    // Sets whether notification posted to this channel should vibrate.
    androidChannel.enableVibration(true);
    // Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this channel
    androidChannel.setLightColor(android.app.Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
    // Sets whether notifications posted to this channel appear on the lockscreen or not
    androidChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(android.app.Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

    getManager(context).createNotificationChannel(androidChannel);
}

private static NotificationManager getManager(Context context) {
    if (mNotificationManager == null) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    return mNotificationManager;
}

/**
 * Downloading push notification image before displaying it in
 * the notification tray
 */


private static class DownLoadBitmap {
    private Context mContext;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    private int mId;
    private Notification mNotification;
    private SimpleTarget target = new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(1024, 512) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
            Logger.d(Logger.TAG, "I got the bitmap");
            showBigNotification(mContext, mBuilder, resource, mId, mNotification);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
            super.onLoadFailed(e, errorDrawable);
            Logger.d(Logger.TAG, "FAILED TO DOWNLOAD RESOURCE"+e.getMessage());
        }
    };

    private DownLoadBitmap(final Context context, final NotificationCompat.Builder builder, final int id, final Notification notification) {
        mContext = context;
        mBuilder = builder;
        mId = id;
        mNotification = notification;
    }

    public void loadFromGlide() {
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(mNotification.getImage())
                .asBitmap()
                .into(target);
    }
}
}
```

I am not understanding why it is creating default channel when I already created the channel and set it as the default channel. That too it happens only if the app is in the background. What can be the issue? How can I resolve it?

Comment: are u using cloud functions?

Comment: firbase push notifications. I suspect the code abortBroadcast() is not working properly in oreo. Not sure.

Comment: you are using notification payload right?

Comment: I am using both notification payload and data payload

Answer (score 1):

You are using both notification and data, but in the `showNotification` you are doing this:

```
bigTextStyle.setBigContentTitle(notification.getTitle());
bigTextStyle.bigText(notification.getBody())
```

In the above you receive the notification payload and add it in the `BigContentTitle` and `BigText`, while the data payload is not getting added, thus when on background(since notification payload is triggered only in foreground), you recieve the default notification.

You need to recieve the data payload, since it gets triggered if the app is on background and foreground.

So you can do this:

```
 bigTextStyle.setBigContentTitle(notification.getData().get("title")); //title name in the data payload
bigTextStyle.bigText(notification.getData().get("body")); //body name in the data payload
```

Also the other like `setSummaryText(..)` ,`setContentTitle(..)`, and `setContentText(..)` need to be changed accordingly.

Comment: I cannot just change the notification to data payload only since iOS device need notification payload

Comment: isn't this on android? I did not say to remove the notification payload, keep it but recieve data payload in the methods above

Comment: The same code works fine in old OS versions. And if I use Firebase Messaging service instead of Receiver then also it works fine. But I am not using it since i need the control over notification even if the app is in background or killed state